# How to remove both axis from a Google Bar Chart (aka Chart API)

Tags: google-visualization

I can't find in the Chart API the way to remove any axis from a bar chart. For instance:

```
cht=bvg
chs=410x150
chd=s:StackOverflow
```

[image: simple bar chart example]

How to remove the gray x and y axis?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please try appending

[&chxt=x,y&chxs=0,000000,10,0,*,000000|1,000000,10,0,*,000000&chxl=0:||1:|](http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?cht=bvg&chs=410x150&chd=s%3aStackOverflow&chxt=x,y&chxs=0,000000,10,0,_,000000|1,000000,10,0,_,000000&chxl=0:||1:|)

[image]

Answer (score 3):

All I found is [this](http://groups.google.com/group/google-chart-api/browse_thread/thread/2435e89a9209b19c/) trick: cover them with a white line and it works

```
cht=bvg
chs=410x150
chd=s:StackOverflow
chm=r,FFFFFF,0,-0.01,0.01,1
    R,FFFFFF,0,-0.01,0.01,1
```

[image]

...but any "cleaner" way?

Comment: AFAIK Bar charts do not support this and always have default axis, line charts do though the sparkline chart type. Perhaps you could use one of these instead?

Answer (score 2):

(based on Alexander Farber's answer, but with some minor improvements)

You can add

```
chxt=x,y
chxs=0,,0,0,_|1,,0,0,_
```

Explanation:

```
chxt=x,y
```

Which axis to show. Even though axis x and y are shown as default, we still need to specify those to be able to apply styling with chxs.

```
chxs=0,,0,0,_|1,,0,0,_
```

Styling for the two axis, separated by pipe. Separated by comma, we have:

- Axis index. Reference to chxt. `0`= first (x), `1`= second (y)
- Label color. Since we will hide the labels, we can leave this empty
- Label font size. Setting this to `0` will hide the labels, and thus we don't need to set empty labels with chxl
- Label alignment. Need to specify a valid value, although we don't display labels. `0` is fine.
- Show axis and tick marks. `_` will hide both

More info at https://developers.google.com/chart/image/docs/chart_params#axis_label_styles 
[image: chart]